# InheritanceManager. How to get field from Inheritance model?

Tags: django

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class Property(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    desc = models.TextField()
    objects = InheritanceManager()

class Apartament(Property):
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
    levels = models.IntegerField()
    something = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views:

```
p = Property.objects.get(slug=slug)
return render_to_response(...{'p':p} ...)
```

templates:

```
{{ p.title }}
```

Can I have access to the fields from `Apartament`?
For example:

```
{{ p.bedrooms }}
```

How to get bedrooms in my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Property.objects.get` method you're calling is the vanilla models.Manager one which just gives you a `Property` object.  You need to use the `get_subclass` method provided by `InheritanceManager` to get an instance of your derived class:

```
p = Property.objects.get_subclass(slug=slug)
```